# Virtual box not installing on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, virtualbox

I am trying to install Virtualbox v 6.1.0 on Mac OS Catalina, but the installation is not successfully completing.
I've read many blogs about allowing the installation in Security in System Preferences but I am not receiving that option to enable at all in the Security.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you trying to install it by direct download? You can try installing it via Homebrew for a much hassle free experience.

Comment: I am trying direct download. It worked on Mojave and it is not working after I upgraded to Catalina.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372492/virtualbox-installation-failed-on-macos-catalina - Check the second solution and try it.

Comment: Thanks Udhy for the suggestion. I tried the second solution. The first point for the uninstall tool works good. But for the second point, the installation package itself is not working. Again no option to allow the installation in the Security under System Preferences.

Comment: @VarunKumarVenugopal You can try installing it using Homebrew Cask.

Comment: @NimeshNeema: Just tried home-brew cask install. Same error in homebrew too :-(